# How do I properly store characters in an array using read?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, buffer

I have written the following code, and I don't understand why read is not storing the characters the way I expect:

```
char temp;
char buf[256];

    while(something)   
        read (in,&temp, 1);
        buf[strlen(buf)] = temp;
     }
```

If I print `temp` and the last place of the `buf` array as I am reading, sometimes they don't match up. For example maybe the character is 'd' but the array contains `%` or the character is `0` and the array contains `.`

I am reading less than 256 characters but it doesn't matter because I am printing as I am reading.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're not initializing `buf` -- `strlen(buf)` is undefined.  You should initialize it like so:

```
buf[0] = 0;
```

Also, it's better to keep track of the length instead of calling `strlen` each iteration to avoid a [Shlemiel the painter algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

You should also be checking for errors in the call to `read(2)` -- if it returns -1 or 0, you should break out of your loop, since it means either an error occurred or you reached the end of the file/input stream.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Read always is successful since i always print the temp variable.
Also the initializing doent help with my problem.
It usually happens well after 100+ characters have been read.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `strlen` in this code. `strlen` relies on it's argument being a `NULL` terminated C string. So unless you initialize your *entire* buffer to `0`, then this code doesn't work.

At any rate `strlen` **isn't** a good choice to use when buffering data, even if you know that you're working with printable string data, if only because `strlen` will traverse the string *every time* just to get your length.

Keep a separate counter, named e.g. `numRead`, only append to `buf` at the `numRead` position, and increment `numRead` by the amount that you read.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I had already made the appropriate corrections with null terminating characters but it doesn't make a difference. The insertion of the characters is done in accordance to what you would normally expect as I can observe this by printing them side by side